# gmail.modify scope Oauth verification for the e2e tests

Tags: gmail-api

[image]

I am trying to modify the access rights to the GMAIL API from readonly to modify scopes as I want to mark the emails as read after I grab the gmail content in my automated e2e tests, but now I see in my Google API Credentials console that I need to submit it for validation where I have to give the home page link and the privacy policy URL (which is not the case as the URL of the test stage is kind of confidential and I am just using the gmail to fw all the emails for the test stage and the GMAIL API to read and mark as read the content).
The E2E Tests is failing when I want to mark as read as of course the permission is not there, but readonly is still working.

Do you have any clue what can I do do enable modify for my automated e2e tests on a test stage?

Thanks a lot!
Elena

Comment: Please add the error you are getting as well as the code you are using.

Comment: Hi, this is what I see in the console, that the verification is required: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvOTM.png

Answer (score 0):

Google has started to crack down on securty.  Depending upon which scope you request your application may have to go though a review process and be approved first.   While you are testing you should be able to develop on your application using the account that created the project in question.

You can read this on the right hand side of the picture

> About the consent screen
>   The consent screen tells your users **who is requesting access to their data** and what kind of data you're asking to access.
>
> OAuth Developer Verification
>   To protect you and your users, **your consent screen may need to be verified by Google**. Without verification, your users will see an additional page indicating that your app is not verified by Google. Learn more
>
> Verification is required if:
>
> - Your application type is public, and
> - **You add a sensitive scope**
>
> Verification may take several days to complete. You will receive email updates as it's processed.
>
> Saving without publishing
>   Even though your consent screen is unpublished, you can still test your application with users with the following limitations:
>
> - Sensitive scopes are limited to 100 grant requests before verification is required
> - Users see an additional page indicating that your app is not verified by Google
> - Let us know what you think about our OAuth experience.